# Date not producing correct result

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to produce a timestamp to the closest millisecond using PHP, I notice in a JavaScript app that I'm trying to replicate they're generating a string like such:

```
2019-10-18T18:50:38.699Z
```

However I'm trying to do the same using this:

```
public function timestamp()
{
    return date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s') . '.' . date('v') . 'Z';
}
```

But I'm getting results like this:

```
2019-10-18T14:51:14.000Z
```

Comment: Is this `date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sZ\Z')` what you are looking for?

Comment: @LucasArbex nope, that's the timezone offset

Comment: From https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php "_Note that date() will always generate 000000 since it takes an integer parameter, whereas DateTime::format() does support microseconds if DateTime was created with microseconds._"

Comment: `$d = new DateTime(); 
echo $d->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v\Z');` https://3v4l.org/21pPT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use DateTime instead of `date()` in order to support microseconds, as @kerbholz brilliantly pointed out on the comments. Try the following, please:

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s\.v\Z');
```

Comment: Also, don't forget to add use DateTime;